# What Properties of a Robot Arm Would Make its C-Space a Genus-2 Torus?

Tags: robotic-arm

Once upon a time, I saw a webpage that had a complete list (with ellipses, of course) of robot arms that have each surface (closed [compact and without boundary], 2-dimensional manifolds) as their c-space (Well, maybe it was just the orientable ones; it was a long time ago). For instance, a spherical pendulum with a rigid rod as the link has $S^2$ as its c-space, and a two-link RR robot arm has the genus-1 torus $T^2$ as its c-space (see Figure 1 below). Would someone know what properties of a robot arm would make its C-Space a genus-2 torus (see Figure 2 below)?

Thanks much in advance, I am keenly interested in the solution to this question.

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 1

[image: Figure 2]
Figure 2

EDIT: I think Figure 3, or perhaps a similar four-bar linkage, may have been a robot arm with the genus-2 torus as its c-space. [image: Figure 3]

Figure 3

Comment: This question might be a good candidate for [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up; I have tried reposting in Asimov's Corner.

Answer (score 1):

The C-space of a robot is tied to its actuators - helical (revolute plus linear) and prismatic (linear) actuators have C-space $\mathbb{R}$ while revolute joints have C-space $S^{1}$. The C-space then of any serial (and probably parallel I'm just not as familiar with these structure) chains is simply the Cartesian product of each individual joint. So, an RRP robot would have C-space $S^{1} \times S^{1} \times \mathbb{R}$.

To answer your question about a genus-2 torus as a robot's C-space, this seems very unlikely to be possible without a good deal of hand-waving magic. As helical and prismatic joints are both non-compact, we would have to rely on revolute joints. It should be noted that even spherical joints can be (and to my best knowledge are) modeled as combinations of revolute joints. Of course an unactuated spherical joint could be seen as having a C-space of $S^{2}$, but once motors are added I think it should be safe to assume the C-space is some number of Cartesian products of $S^{1}$.

So, how would we obtain:

$$ (S^{1} \times S^{1}) \ \# \ (S^1{} \times S^{1}) $$

where $\#$ is the [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum)? Considering this is the gluing of two torus together over some "slices" we have cut into each torus - we could view this as the C-space having some smoothly changing actuation features - where once some threshold has been crossed, we have reached a C-space in some ways disjoint from our previous C-space. I think perhaps what could accomplish this would be three revolute joints, such that joints 1 actuates the robot when joint 2 has some configuration parameter $-\frac{\pi}{4} \lt \theta \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$, they both actuate the robot when $\frac{\pi}{4} \lt \theta \lt \frac{\pi}{2} $ or $ -\frac{\pi}{2} \lt \theta \lt -\frac{\pi}{4} $, and finally joint 3 actuates the robot when $-\pi \lt \theta \lt -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} \lt \theta \lt \pi$ (these are not really disconnected - just an unfortunate side effect of using real numbers to represent $S^{1}$) (also I did not set equalities properly because I am lazy). As a final note, this construction is not completely accurate as far as I can tell. It appears joint 1 and/or joint 3 would have to be in certain configurations for the proposed "crossover" to happen. Also, I'm not entirely sure what the link structure would be either. There's likely many other issues with this - but it's a start.

So, perhaps such a robot is possible, but it is very, very unlikely that one exists already - plus the fact that the mechanical design of such a robot would be... difficult to say the least.

---

I did not notice you were asking for more than exclusively genus-2 torus C-space robots. Any sort of arm structure will have a genus-1 torus C-space. Any robot driven directly, or through a gear train, by motors will have a genus-1 torus C-space. It seems like these would satisfy what you are most interested in - so I would avoid anything with linear or helical actuators.

---

The C-space of figure 3 is a 2-dimensional compact manifold. We know it is 2 dimensional as there is a general formula for open chain manipulators - dimension of manifold is equal to $n - m$ when not at singular configurations (this will not affect every point on the manifold, but will increase the dimension of the manifold above $n-m$ at specific points). This is done by considering the closed chain manipulator as an open chain manipulator and using our knowledge of the inverse kinematics solutions for fixed end-effector locations.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! Please see Figure 3 above and see if it or the four-bar linkage version of it is relevant

Comment: The included figure is what is referred to as a closed chain serially linked rigid body. Everything I have mentioned above is assuming you have an open chain - so imagine link 3 in the figure is not constrained to the ground. This is an interesting case though, because the C-space is constrained to the configurations such that the end link has a constant position. Another way we can consider this problem is that of the constant end-effector position with non-zero joint velocity (i.e. being able to move our joints without moving the end-effector). This is referred to as null-motion.

Comment: Thanks again so much for replying! So, admittedly, I'm very ignorant about the topics involved currently. Having said that, does anyone know 1) if the closed chain robot arm in Figure 3 above has the genus-2 torus as its c-space or 2) what ope or closed chain robot arm might have the genus-2 torus as its c-space

Comment: The C-space of a closed chain robot like the one you have listed will depend on its kinematic parameters (L1, L2,...). It's possible that it could have the C-space you are looking for - given specific parameters. It's also more possible that it doesn't. I would recommend looking into Joel Burdick's work on kinematic analysis of redundant robots as a start. More recent work uses topological properties to handle fault-tolerance - so that is another avenue to pursue. Generally speaking, much of what you are asking for would require specific parameters and many minutes of numerical computation.

Answer (score 0):

This webpage [https://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/People/Eldar/thesis/index.html](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/People/Eldar/thesis/index.html) has a partial answer; it creates robot arms with c-space an orientable surface with exponentially-increasing genus, of a sequence beginning g = 1, 0, 0 1, 5, 17, ... . (You will need this plugin on Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein.)